# Where can i find the default style for a WPF DataGridRow

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Any idea where i could find the default style XAML for the WPF DataGridRow?

The goal is to change the color of the row when you hover over it or select it. i dont like the ugly blue :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the default style for any built-in control using tools like [Show Me The Template](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/Posts/Details/2091), [Style Snooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/), or the [BAML Viewer](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BamlViewer) add-in for Reflector

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I think I can be helpful, also because most of the links of the accepted answer aren't working now...

I use to do like this:

- open Microsoft Blend (it comes with Visual Studio)
- create a new WPF project (just for this, than you can delete it)
- add a new `DataGrid` to your page/window
- right click on the `DataGrid` > Edit additional template > Edit `RowStyle` > Edit copy
- choose where you want Blend to generate the XAML and confirm

Now you have the complete XAML for the `DataGridRow` style.

In this way you can get the XAML of every WPF/Silverlight control.

*PS. some menu entries may differ from what I wrote because my Visual Studio language is not english*