# GridView Column Header style

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, coding-style, datagrid

The Datagrid has much nicer looking column headers (gradient, etc). Does someone have some XAML that mimics the style the Datagrid uses for a GridView?

**UPDATE**

I found something very close, but still not identical:

```
       <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Grid x:Name="Root">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF448DCA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#7FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[3].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#CCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[2].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[1].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF448DCA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#D8FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[0].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#C6FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[1].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#8CFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[2].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#3FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[3].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SortStates">
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Unsorted"/>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="SortAscending">
                                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon"/>
                                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="SortDescending">
                                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon"/>
                                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-.9" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon"/>
                                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FF1F3B53" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Stretch="Fill">
                                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015"/>
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"/>
                                                                        <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                </Rectangle>
                                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}" FontWeight="Bold" Width="10" Grid.Column="1" />
                                                        <Path x:Name="SortIcon" Grid.Column="2" Data="F1 M -5.215,6.099L 5.215,6.099L 0,0L -5.215,6.099 Z " Fill="#FF444444" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="8">
                                                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY=".9" ScaleX=".9"/>
                                                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                        </Path>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalSeparator" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Sorry dude - here's the right one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421561/where-can-i-find-the-default-style-for-a-wpf-datagridrow

Answer (score 0):

This theme Might help

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type WpfToolkit:DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HeaderBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource HeaderBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1" />   
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                Path=Content}"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="300" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>  

<!-- DataGridColumnHeader Right Gripper Style -->
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderRightGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<!-- DataGridColumnHeader Left Gripper Style -->
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderLeftGripperStyle" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderRightGripperStyle}" 
       TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Canvas>
                        <Line RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stroke="#88B0E4"
                              X1="7" Y1="{Binding ElementName=Border, Path=ActualHeight}"
                              X2="7" Y2="0"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```